q-factor in the Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction
The Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction is defined by $$R(q)=\cfrac{q^{1/5}}{1+\cfrac{q}{1+\cfrac{q^2}{1+\cfrac{q^3}\ddots}}}.$$ I would like to know role played by the factor $q^{1/5}$ and why not some other q-factors. I studied only $q$-series and partitions. Is there any explanation for this factor via $q$-series and partitions? In this post (The complete list of continued fractions like the Rogers-Ramanujan?), they have mentioned several continued fractions for 4,5,6,8,12.  For the degree 5, is this the only continued fraction?

Look at the excellent Wikipedia article about this CF: the $q^{1/5}$ is the only exponent which makes $R(q)=R(e^{2\pi i\tau})$ behave like a modular function (of weight 0). As a consequence, it has CM properties: when $\tau$ is of the form $a+b\sqrt{D}$ with $D<0$ and $a,b$ rational, it is an algebraic number. More generally, if you work with $q$-identities, they ALWAYS become simpler if you multiply them by a suitable fractional power of $q$ making them modular (if possible of course): try it with Euler's pentagonal theorem about Dedekind's eta function.

My answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754128/modular-forms-and-the-roger-ramanujan-identities-how may help.
